# Redraw Graph on JUNG

Tags: java, graph, jung

I build a graph using JUNG (Java Universal Network/Graph Framework) with the following code:

```
g = new SparseMultigraph<BusStop, Travel>();

//add some Vertex and Edges

Layout<String, String> layout1 = new CircleLayout(g);
layout1.setSize(new Dimension(300,300)); // sets the initial size of the layout space

VisualizationViewer vv = new VisualizationViewer(layout1);
vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,350)); //Sets the viewing area size

Transformer<BusStop,Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<BusStop,Paint>() {
    public Paint transform(BusStop b) {
        return Color.GREEN;
    }
};

Transformer<BusStop,Shape> vertexShape = new Transformer<BusStop,Shape>() {
    public Shape transform(BusStop b) {
        return new Rectangle(-20, -10, 40, 20);
    }
};

vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexPaint);
vv.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer(vertexShape);
vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);

GraphViewerForm = new edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.GraphZoomScrollPane(vv);
```

Now, I want to add more vertices and edges to the graph.. how can I do this? What instructions should I run for the graph to be redrawn? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for redrawing the graph after user interaction, you have to add an *EditingModalGraphMouse* to your *VisualizationViewer*

```
    EditingModalGraphMouse gm = new EditingModalGraphMouse(vv.getRenderContext(), 
             vertexFactory, edgeFactory); 
    vv.setGraphMouse(gm);
```

the constructor must be fed with *vertexFactory* and *edgeFactory* objects derived from

```
Factory<E> and Factory<V>
```

whose job is to create a new instance of edge/vertices class via the *create()* method

```
Factory <BusStop> vertexFactory = new Factory<BusStop>() {
            public BusStop create() {
                return new BusStop();
            }
        };
```

same for the *edgeFactory*

Answer (score 5):

After adding edges and vertices to the graph, you must call `vv.repaint()` to draw the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add vertices and edges:

```
//add some Vertex and Edges
g.addVertex((BusStop)obj1);
g.addVertex((BusStop)obj2);
g.addEdge((Travel) trv1, obj1, obj2);
```

For example see how **addVertex** and **addEdge** is being used in [SimpleGraphView.java](http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/SimpleGraphView.java)

Comment: I know that :) My problem is that the graph is only refreshed when I move the scrollbar.. Thanks

Comment: After you add the nodes call vv.repaint().